# What is the file named linux_signing_key.pub in the home folder and can I delete it?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, repository, delete, pgp

I found a file `linux_signing_key.pub` in my home folder.
What is it for?
Can I safely delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An answer in the Ubuntu forums helped](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2345252&p=13577945#post13577945):
**Short version: Usually it is a PGP key and it can be safely deleted.**
**Details**: I installed a **new PPA/repository** to the software sources recently. The install process and configuring of the new software source included downloading the signing key for that source and then importing the key. Probably I did it by copy/pasting some terminal commands. The `linux_signing_key.pub` is the key I downloaded, and assuming it imported without problems I don't need the file any more and can delete it.

Software repositories uses PGP keys to verify that the programs you download actually come from the sources you have configured on you computer, and nobody has messed around with the files.